# Display rows on a webpage from a function that uses mysqli to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have the following code in PHP that contains a function which uses mysqli to retrieve data from my database:

```
function displayuser(){
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shop") or die("Error");
      $query = "SELECT id, username FROM users";
      $result = $db->query($query) or die("Error");
      while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
          return $row['id'].' '.$row['username'];
      }
}
```

My question is; how would I go about displaying **$row['id']** and **$row['username']** in a webpage using HTML presuming I would have to use PHP as well?

Should it be like this? Say in a PHP file **user.php** for instance

```
<?php
   include_once('function.php');
   foreach(displayuser() as $display) {
?>
       <p><?php echo $display['id'];?></p>
<?php
   }
?>
```

I used the display method above when I was handling **mysql** rather than **mysqli**, so I'm trying to familiarize myself with the improved mysql

EDIT (new code):

`functions.php`

```
function getuser() {

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shop") or die("Error");

$query = "SELECT id, username FROM users";

$result = $db->query($query) or die();

return $result->fetch_all(); }
```

`display.php`

```
<?php 
include_once('functions.php');

foreach(getuser() as $user) {

  echo $user['id']. ' '.$user['username'];
}
?>
```

When executing, **display.php** displays empty results.
I tried using **print_r** to print in the data behind the arrays but it seems the arrays were empty. I thought maybe we shouldn't use "foreach" or something.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the keyword return literally kills your script. Return means 'go back to what called me'. That said, the first row from your query will end the displayUser function. Restructure it like this:

```
$result = $db->query($query);
return $result->fetch_all();
```

Then the rest should work but I would reword and structure it.

```
include_once('function.php');
foreach(displayuser() as $user) {
    echo "<p>" . $user['id'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: I seem to grasp the whole concept now, thanks a lot for the help. However, I think I'm doing something wrong cause given that I'm applying your approach, I seem to be getting empty/blank results when echoing the data out. Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Edit your question with your new code so I can look at what you changed.

Comment: Found a solution. Thanks for your help and everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there, you could go about doing it like this:

`function.php`

```
function get_users(){
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shop") or die("Error");
      $query = "SELECT id, username FROM users";
      $result = $db->query($query) or die("Error");
      return $result->fetch_all();
}
```

Display File

```
<?php
   include_once('function.php');
   $users = get_users();
   foreach($users as $user) {
       echo '<p>' . $user['id'] . ' ' . $user['username'] . '</p>';
   }
?>
```

This has a more clear separation of concerns, no HTML in the function call so it can be reused multiple times reducing duplicate code.